# Apache Flink: Reading parquet files from S3 in Data Stream APIs

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-flink, parquet

We have several external jobs producing small (500MiB) parquet objects on S3 partitioned by time. The goal is to create an application that would read those files, join them on a specific key and dump the result into a Kinesis stream or another S3 bucket.

Can it be achieved by just the means of Flink? Can it monitor and load new S3 objects being created and load them into the application?

Answer (score 1):

The newer `FileSource` class (available in recent Flink versions) supports monitoring a directory for new/modified files. See `FileSource.forBulkFileFormat()` in particular, for reading Parquet files.

You use the `FileSourceBuilder` returned by the above method call, and then `.monitorContinuously(Duration.ofHours(1));` (or whatever interval makes sense).

Comment: If directories are partitioned by time, we need to kill job after certain time right ? otherwise this will monitor old directories unnecessarily when it is expected to have nothing written to those old directories.

Is there a efficient way to not create new jobs frequently and also monitor only current hour directories ?